# How to remove authorization header on the redirection of http response in SuiteScript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

How to remove authorization header on the redirection of http response in SuiteScript 2.0?

I have a script in NetSuite using SuiteScript 2.0 to calling 3rd party api. The Api is using  AWS. When i calling the api is returning :

"`Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified</Message><ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>Bearer xxxxx</ArgumentValue>`".

the xxx is only censored text.

Here is my code :

```
  function getPatient() {
    var header = [];
    header["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    header["Authorization"] = "Bearer xxxxxxcensoredkey123";
    try {
      var response = https.get({
        url: "https://api2.xxxxx.com/api/test",
        headers: header,
      });

      return response.body;
    } catch (err) {
      log.error("ERROR", JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  }
```

I had test in postman all is working well. Only NetSuite cant. Then I try calling it with php just for another test and surprisingly it because redirection response. any sample code or possible solution for this issue?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Instead of setting the headers, have you tried to include the authentication into the query parameters? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html According to different fora, it's related the redirects processed by AWS.

Comment: @W.S. Not tried yet but my only data that i get from 3rd party company (api provider) is only bearer token. Is it possible using query param?